# No able to build apk for test

Tags: android, react-native

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit
>   '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 57

I am trying to build the apk using following command

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

cd android
./gradlew assembleDebug

but I am always getting

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not open settings remapped class cache for 4mbnl7wyuojndhdwxo65gs7ee
>     (/Users/blickx/.gradle/caches/5.5/scripts-remapped/settings_1v1qun8lpm94pweyy1199ydnb/4mbnl7wyuojndhdwxo65gs7ee/settings74e694b976d6abaa826c8abac43e9de8).
>
>   > Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/blickx/Desktop/dumont-reactnative/Dumont/android/settings.gradle'
>   >     (/Users/blickx/.gradle/caches/5.5/scripts/4mbnl7wyuojndhdwxo65gs7ee/settings/settings74e694b976d6abaa826c8abac43e9de8).
>   >     BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 57
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

It will Create Apk in Debug-mode.

Comment: This will create the build with remote server. I want it without remote server